# Way to search for a specific user's comments across all of YouTube

Tags: youtube

On YouTube, how do I search across the site for a specific YouTuber's comments? I'm looking for something more advanced than the [Hadzy](https://hadzy.com/) site.

Comment: ***"something more advanced"*** Hadzy describes itself as a dynamic, user-friendly platform for deep-diving into YouTube comments. with a comprehensive suite of features like search, sort, and analysis.  You should [edit] your question to explain what you mean by ***advanced***.  What features do you need from any recommended web app or software?